# Unable to make multiple plots in one plot In ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to make multiple plots one by one by keeping one variable at x cordinate and rest changing at the Y coordinate.
I am not able to bring all of the plots in one plot.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Locus_Name, y=PIC, group=1)) + 
geom_line() + geom_point(color="orange")
```

This is the code that I use for my plotting and I keep changing the variable of Y but new graph comes up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multiple functions into one plot (ggplot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879802/combining-multiple-functions-into-one-plot-ggplot)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52436487/show-multiple-plots-from-ggplot-on-one-page-in-r

Comment: @RussThomas I believe thatyour suggestion could help but I am new to coding stuff so I need help in defining the columns and understanding the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're looking for a basic understanding of how `ggplot` works here and how to format and access your data to produce (in this case) a line plot with multiple series of y values (sharing the same x value).  A reasonable place to start would be with the [multitude](http://r-statistics.co/Complete-Ggplot2-Tutorial-Part1-With-R-Code.html) of [tutorials](https://uc-r.github.io/ggplot_intro) available [online](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/).  Here's a crash course on how to get what I believe you are looking to do.

### Prepare your data

The first step toward creating a plot is to prepare your data.  From your description, it seems the data is formatted for you with the same x values applied to different y values.  It's not clear to me if those exist in different datasets or if they are are in the same data frame as different columns; however, the approach here is similar in that the goal is to arrive at a data frame which respects [Tidy Data Principles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Take the following example dataset:

```
# using these libraries for this example
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(circular)

# example dataset.  Each y# column has values for the same x column (locus)
df <- data.frame(
  locus=c(1:500),
  y1=rnorm(500,1,0.05),
  y2=cos(rad(1:500)),
  y3=sin(rad(1:500)),
  y4=rnorm(500,-1.3,0.1)
)
```

In our example dataset, `df`, we have a problem in that each of the y columns contain *two* pieces of information:

1. The **type** of y: y1 contains one series, y2 another, etc...
2. The **value** of y: each number represents the value of that type of y at a particular x value (locus)

The goal is to have a column for x values, a column for y values, and a column for y type.  For this, we need to *gather* together the y1, y2, y3... columns, and separate these terms.  For this, I'm using `dplyr` and `tidyr` and the `gather()` function.

```
# combine all y1, y2, y3 columns to create a type and value column.  Ignore the locus col.
df <- df %>% gather(key='type_of_y', value='value_of_y', -locus)
```

Now you have a dataset that is "long".  This can also be done using `melt()` from the package `reshape2` or `pivot_longer()` from the `tidyverse` packages.

### Plot your data

The plot is pretty easy to create now.  You specify the dataframe, `df`, and then within the aesthetics, we would assign `x=locus` and `y=value_of_y`.  In order to create separate lines for each original y column, you set `color=type_of_y`.  That makes a separate line for each differentiated by color.  You can also use `linetype=type_of_y` to set a different linetype for each type of y.  If you combine both, you'll see the combined effects of both.  The simple case for different color lines is here:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=locus, y=value_of_y, color=type_of_y)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point(size=0.3)
```

[image]